# Does "carriage" mean that I am on my own on this SNCF itinerary?

Tags: sncf

I am using the [SNCF Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sncf.fusion) to plan a trip to a small French city.

While the first leg of the trip is by the TGV, the second leg is by "carriage".

My dictionary explains "carriage" as either:

- *A rail car, especially one designed for the conveyance of passengers.*
- *A wheeled vehicle, generally drawn by horse power.*

But the icon looks awfully like a personal car. And the map icon on the right opens the system's itinerary app.

[image]

**My question**: Is that leg provided by SNCF and included in the ticket's price? Or are they telling me that I am on my own for that leg?

Comment: It would be helpful if you reveal exactly which itinerary you are searching for (from, to, time of travel). When I search for travel possibilities from Angers to Thouars, I only get regular train connections, most with a transfer in Saumur.

Comment: This is the SNCF's version of a "door to door" itinerary. You usually only see those non-public transport segments when you pick an origin or destination which is not a train station (so they include getting to/from the train station), but apparently in this case they deemed it a better option...

Comment: Confusingly, "voiture" is also used by SNCF to refer to train carriages, as in "Voiture 7 place 23".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This actually means "travel on your own". The trip between Angers Saint-Laud and Thouars in your itinerary is neither included in your ticket nor operated by SNCF.

Have a look at the output from the scnf website below: 
You didn't state the date you were looking for, so I just chose next Sunday. The connection by train is quite bad, so they show you how long you would need taking a car instead of train. This is a standard feature (unless you deselect the car option in the "transport type" menu) - you're offered the fastest connections along with more convenient or cheaper options.

[image: Example itinerary from website]